# Segmentation Fault when I use popen()

Tags: c, popen

I have a function to encrypt some string.
It's fabulous but ... it's bug :(

I can use the function one time, but the second time, crash.

Thank you ! :)

I working with bash ubuntu (W10), no warning (and error) when i compile my project.

```c
char * encryptPassword(char * string){
    printf("DEBUT\n");
    FILE *fp=NULL;
    char path[1035];
    char password[32];
    //char * password = NULL; //for the encrypt password
    printf("MALLOC\n");
    //password = (char *)malloc(33*sizeof(char));
    char * result = NULL;
    char chaine[128] = "echo "; 
    char end_chaine[128] = " | openssl md5 | cut -d ' ' -f2"; 
    //Create the command
    printf("STRCAT\n");
    strcat(chaine,string); 
    strcat(chaine,end_chaine); 
    //Execute
    printf("POPEN %s\n",chaine);
    fp = popen(chaine, "r");
    //Reclaim the encrypted password
    printf("GETS\n");
    fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp);
    pclose(fp);
    //To remove the character '\n'
    printf("SPRINTF\n");
    sprintf(password,"%32s",path);
    result = strtok(password,"\n");
    printf("%s\n",result);
    //OK IT'S FINISH !
    return (result);
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `popen`?

Comment: `sprintf(password,"%32s",path);` should say `31` because the array is `char password[32];`. Strangely you replaced `password = (char *)malloc(33*sizeof(char));`. I guess you should have `char password[33];`

Comment: Don't use arbitrary buffer lengths on strings which are pre-defined. `char* chaine = "echo"`. This will prevent you from thinking about concatenating to them, because you shouldn't. Instead use a buffer specifically for concatenation. This code appears to be riddled with wild assumptions about the length of various strings, so you probably have a multitude of buffer overrun problems here.

Comment: On top of all this, **MD5 IS NOT IN ANY WAY SUITABLE FOR HASHING PASSWORDS**. It's far too weak and shorter passwords can be cracked almost instantly using modern tools. The absolute baseline these days is a password-specific hash with variable difficulty like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Comment: I know it fo md5 but thank you :)

Comment: What input do you feed into your function. What is the result of the `echo ...` command if you execute it manually?

Comment: The good result

Comment: you have 3 _chances_ to have an undefined behavior (e.g. typically a crash), 2 possible and 1 sure, see my answer

Comment: There are much easier and much more reliable ways to hash a string than running `openssl` via `popen()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Segmentation Fault when I use popen()

your problem is probably here :

> ```
>  strcat(chaine,string);
> ```

if the input parameter *string* more the other fields are too large for *chaine* and in that case you write out of it with an undefined behavior (it seems a crah in your case)

Compute the needed length then allocate the string before to fill it.

Note you can do that in a lazy way with two calls to *snprintf*, a first to compute the needed size and the second to fill the command. Is a lazy way because here you just concatenate strings, you don't write numbers etc needing a non constant size.

---

However is can be also here after the *popen* :

> ```
> sprintf(password,"%32s",path);
> ```

because *password* is sized 32 and *sprintf* will writes 33 character to also place the final null character

---

And if miraculously you return from the function you will probably not survive of the use of the result because it is NULL or **a pointer to the stack not anymore valid** : *password* is a local variable so *strtok* returns NULL or the address of *password* becoming the result of the function